# Group by with Order by DESC not working using PHP MySQL codes

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, phpmyadmin

I have three tables,
table one name (**tbl_brands**) with these columns:

[image]

and second table name (**tbl_loader_attachment**) with these columns:

[image]

and the third table name is (**tbl_images**) with these columns:

[image]

I used this query below to sort brands DESC:

```
SELECT tbl_loader_attachment.*, tbl_brands.* ,tbl_images.* FROM tbl_loader_attachment
INNER JOIN tbl_brands ON(tbl_brands.b_id=tbl_loader_attachment.b_id)
INNER JOIN tbl_images ON(tbl_images.la_id=tbl_loader_attachment.la_id)
WHERE tbl_loader_attachment.type_brand_id=1
GROUP BY tbl_images.b_id ORDER BY tbl_loader_attachment.la_id DESC
```

When I run this code only get the first row appear I want to get only the newest brand appear when I inserted,  in my tables I want to in the **tbl_loader_attachment** get row 4, and in the **tbl_images** get row 8 at the same time but when I used group by only the first row appear.

this is my Output:

[image]

How i can fix?

Comment: @Akina when I used group by only get the first row, I want to get la end row when I inserted to my tables.

Comment: please describe what you are trying to receive and provide example of desired result

Comment: @Nikita I edit my question add output to this, when I run my code only get the first row I want to in the **tbl_loader_attachment** get row 4, and in the **tbl_images** get row 8.

Comment: *when I used group by only get the first row* Oops, I didn't see GROUP BY. In this case you must use more complex method. In tagged versions you may enumerate row in specified order using user-defined variable (emulating ROW_NUMBER() - search), then select only a row with this number = 1 in outer query.

Comment: could you provide all data as text please

Comment: @nbk I could only one last row selected for every brand model with one image

Comment: to test your select and provide an idea, we need the data as text or as dbfoddle . nobody wants to type them in, ne ce pas

Comment: The `GROUP BY` seems to be improper.  (Unless _all_  the other selected columns are dependent on it.)